# Javascript - Load one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have Javascript loading some data and because its in a loop it ends up loading multiple times which causes lengthy wait times. I need to find how to load it only once. I researched the issue and found some code but not sure how to implement it. Here is the best link I could find about my issue:

http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/10/11/preventing-javascript-files-from-loading-multiple-times/

**Update:** Sorry it took so long to get back. I just work Wednesday through Saturday. I was asked to give my entire code. I trimmed it down considerably.

**Script I'm Loading to pull only once**

```
jQuery(function($)
        {
  $('#resultA').load('DocText.html #Tablemain1');
  $('#resultB').load('DocText.html #Tablemain2');
```

**Entire Code**

```
table class="tblrohs6" border="5" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName( "title" ).item(0); 
    document.write('<iframe src="http://some.company.com/mfgsupt/testeng/eac/b4home/city/abistatus.asp?Bldg=City&abiID='+title.innerHTML+'&Training=no" id="abiIframe" Name="abiIframe" width="550" height="55" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" ></iframe>');
    </script>
    <SCRIPT SRC="file://///namp-dsk-003/cim-cam/CAM/BOI/Abi/680/Common_Files/TitleCheck.js"></SCRIPT>

    </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <!----------------StartMain Table Placement-------------------------->

      <p class="revisionmain"> Text List - Assembly Build Instructions</p>    

      <script>
            $('#resultA').load('DocText.html #Tablemain1');
            $('#resultB').load('DocText.html #Tablemain2');
      </script>

            <p id="resultA"></p>

        <!---------------Start Assembly Buttons-------------------------------> 
      <table width="80%" border="1" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="10"><div align="center" class="row-column-headers-RoHS">Assembly Selection</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="center"><button id="b1" onclick="showX(2)"> 178-0416-00 </button></div></td>
          <td><div align="center"><button id="b2" onclick="showX(3)"> 178-0427-00 </button></div></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="9">
              <div align="center"><button onclick="location.reload();"> Refresh </button></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <!-------------------End Assembly Button------------------------------->

            <p id="resultB"></p>            
            <p id="resultC"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <!--------------------End Main Table Placement--------------------------->
  <tr>
    <td class="bodycell"><p class="section">Lower Level Casing </p>
        <table style="visibility:visible" width="100%" border="2">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><ol start="1">
<!----------------------------------Body After Tables------------------------------------------------>
            <p id="result1"></p>
            <p id="result2"></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-------------------------------------- END Body After Tables------------------------------------------>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--------------- Start Column Selector for button--------Input at end of this doc----------->
    <script>

    function showX(num) {;

<!--------------- Start Column Selector for button--------Input at end of this doc----------->

<!--------------------- Start Search Column for None------------------------>   
var tab = document.getElementById('part1Table');
var l = tab.rows.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    var tr = tab.rows[i];
    var cll = tr.cells[num];                                                              
    if(s = cll.innerText.indexOf('None') != -1) 
    {
<!---------------------- End Search Column for None------------------------->   
<!---------------- Start Place Lines in Document--------------------->

    jQuery(function($)
        {
                $('#resultA').load('DocText.html #Tablemain1');
                $('#resultB').load('DocText.html #Tablemain2');

                if (num==2) {
                $('#resultE').load('DocText.html #0416');}
                if (num==3) {
                $('#resultF').load('DocText.html #0427');}


                $('#result1').load('DocText.html #Line1');
                $('#result2').load('DocText.html #Line2');

        });
<!------------------ End Place Lines in Document----------------------->


if (i==1)                                                   /*Change this for "Line in ABI Doc" */
  { var e = document.getElementById('result1');             /*Change this for "Line Hidden" */
        e.style.display = 'none';}

if (i==2)                                                   /*Change this for "Line in ABI Doc" */
  { var e = document.getElementById('result2');             /*Change this for "Line Hidden" */
        e.style.display = 'none';}


}}} </script>


<!-------------------------------------Start Pull part1Table Data ---------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($)
        {
            $('#resultZZ').load('DataTableUpdate3.html #part1Table');
        });         
    </script>

        <p id="resultZZ"></p>
<!--This is for Button Column Selector, Very Important -->      
        <input type="text" id="cellnum" value="0"/>
<!--This is for Button Column Selector, Very Important -->
```

Comment: whoa - that's a mess. Can you try to explain in a few sentences what you're trying to do here? And have a look at http://angularjs.org/ (or other frameworks helping you dealing with data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking closer to the code and was able to take my .loads out of the loop. Now as a result it is no longer reloading the same objects multiple times. Thank for all the input. I guess sometimes re-organizing makes all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know, your `showX(num)` function on line 73 of your given code, you have a broken function that isn't going to run.

```
function showX(num) {;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a variable and check if it is set.

Example:

```
if (!window.dataIsLoaded) {
    // load the data
}

window.dataIsLoaded = true;
```

But of course it would be much better to avoid executing this part of the code in some loop. You should provide more context to understand what you're doing and why the data would be loaded in a loop.

Comment: Sorry didn't want to bore with details. We have a 50 x 10 table. My code searches one column at a time for the word "none" and does this in a loop. Once it find "none" that corresponds to a part that won't be on this board it removes that from another document. Here is the loop. var tab = document.getElementById('part1Table'); var l = tab.rows.length; for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) { var tr = tab.rows[i]; var cll = tr.cells[num]; if(s = cll.innerText.indexOf('None') != -1) {

Comment: @JohnB -- Update your question with the code you tried to stuff into the comment.